# Need Help converting to python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need some help converting the following to 2.7 from 3.6. Made it for someone now they want it in 2.7 :/ - Appreciate any help. Having a tough time. Some reason it is outputting all 0's - maybe some of the operators have changed?

https://hastebin.com/yazisebewa.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try future statements. Basically, keep the code the way it is, and *backport* features to 2.7. I already see the `print` statements causing problems, so at the top just add `from __future__ import print_statement`. This will cause Python 2.7 to read `print` as if it were running in 3.x. Running the code through trial and error, backporting features as needed might be the best way to accomplish your goal. I will be happy to help with any further problems.

Comment: Thanks! Also, any reason why it is outputting 0 in 2.7 but in 3.6 it works...?

Comment: File "KOAPvECalculator.py", line 1
    from __future__ import print_statement
SyntaxError: future feature print_statement is not defined

Comment: In 2.x, division would return integers. To fix this, add ", division" to your future statement. Also it is called "__future__" not "future". (Two underscores on each side)

Comment: Oh, never mind (the two underscores were interpreted by stackOverflow as bold). Turns out it is called "print_function" not "print_statement". I'll try to be more accurate next time.